# Prevent graph from panning

Tags: javascript, graph, sigma.js

Disable graph zooming can be done by settings - but I can't find no way to turn off panning of the graph. I tried to prevent dragging by binding a `clickStage` event, but I can't figure out how to prevent default events from getting called. Something like `event.preventDefault()` or `event.stopProgagation()` would do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [this](https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/issues/574) and [this](https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/issues/251) sigma.js issues I found a workaround which permits me to maintain the graph in the visual area - but still would be interested to totally prevent the graph from panning.

I manage to bounce my graph back into original location when panning. When `coordinatesUpdated` event gets triggered by the `camera` I use `camera.goTo()` function to move the graph back to 0/0.

```
s.cameras[0].bind('coordinatesUpdated', function(e) {
   if (s.cameras[0].x < 0) s.cameras[0].x = 0;
   if (s.cameras[0].y < 0) s.cameras[0].y = 0;
   if (s.cameras[0].x > 0) s.cameras[0].x = 0;
   if (s.cameras[0].y > 0) s.cameras[0].y = 0;
});
```